# Extends Object.setPrototypeOf() vs Object.create

Tags: javascript

I know two ways to inherit function constructor.

Option 1 **Object.create**

```
function x(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

x.prototype.XDD = function() {};


function y(c, r) {
  x.call(this, 1, 2);
  this.r = r;
  this.c = c;
}

y.prototype = Object.create(x.prototype);
y.prototype.YDD = function() {};
y.prototype.XDD = function() {};
y.prototype.constructor  = y;

var rect = new y(1, 2);
```

Option 2 **Object.setPrototypeOf()**

```
function x(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

x.prototype.XDD = function() {};

function y(c, r) {
  x.call(this, 1, 2);
  this.r = r;
  this.c = c;
}

y.prototype.YDD = function() {};
y.prototype.XDD = function() {};
Object.setPrototypeOf(y.prototype, x.prototype);

var rect = new y(1, 2);
```

What are the differences between them ?.And there is another solution better than these ?.

Comment: to answer the last question, yes, there is: `class Foo extends Bar`

Comment: Upto Preference -JS is based on `prototypal inheritance`, `Object.create` which is very much for this one only. But people who more experienced with `class and object` prefer the `class` keyword

Comment: Notwithstanding performance issues, using `Object.setPrototypeOf()` also suggests that you might want to change the prototype _after_ the event. I can’t think of a realistic example of _why_ you need to do this, but there you go.

Answer (score 3):

According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf):

> Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how
>   modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, currently a very
>   slow operation in every browser and JavaScript engine. In addition,
>   the effects of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are
>   not limited to simply the time spent in the Object.setPrototypeOf(...)
>   statement, but may extend to any code that has access to any object
>   whose [[Prototype]] has been altered.
>
> Because this feature is a part of the language, it is still the burden
>   on engine developers to implement that feature performantly (ideally).
>   Until engine developers address this issue, if you are concerned about
>   performance, you should avoid setting the [[Prototype]] of an object.
>   Instead, create a new object with the desired [[Prototype]] using
>   Object.create().

Performance comparsion (Feb 14 2019):
https://gist.github.com/calebmer/c74e2a7941044e5f28b8#gistcomment-2836415

In short it looks like using `Object.create` **is much faster** then `Object.setPrototypeOf` when used at *extremely* larger scale.

There are many other ways to *to set the prototype of an object* in JS (like unrecommended use of `Object.prototype.__proto__` ) but nowadays (Oct 2019) the most recommended way seems to be the use of ES6 `class`, [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class) by most modern browsers. While there are benchmarks (like: [this](http://incaseofstairs.com/six-speed/)) that indicates that ES6 classes and `super()` are slower than thier ES5 counterparts, it makes your code cleaner especially for people from other OOP languages.

Comment: That benchmark does a very different thing than the OPs code.

Comment: Not a very different - it's essentially shows the difference between `Object.create` and `Object.setPrototypeOf`

Comment: But the performance difference of an `Object.create` call vs an `Object.setPrototype` call is irrelevant to the OPs code. There is only a single call to them, and whether that takes 3ns longer or not won't matter. He only would care if there was a difference for `var rect = new y(1, 2);` or `rect.YDD()`.

Comment: Actually the question is not about creating objects or calling methods, but he asks about 2 ways of inheritance: `Object.create` vs `Object.setPrototypeOf`. I agree with you that in most cases you don't inherit 10^8 times, but the question is explicitly about the inheritance.